# How can I run a method when someone types in a TextInput box?

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a typing practice program, and I want to check if someone typed the correct phrase in TextInput, every time they enter a character.

I have tried using keyboard_on_key_down: root.CheckIfCorrect() to run the function and that raises an error the moment I click on the text input box.
https://pastebin.com/nqU7bXcn

Here's my code
main.py

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import random

Builder.load_file("main.kv")
sentences = [
    "My own brother, Aberforth, was prosecuted for practicing inappropriate charms on a goat. It was all over the papers, but did Aberforth hide? No, he did not! He held his head high and went about his business as usual! Of course, I'm not entirely sure he can read, so that may not have been bravery."
]


class TitleScreen(Screen):
    def SwitchMain(self):
        sm.switch_to(MainScreen(name="main"))


class MainScreen(Screen):
    chosen = random.choice(sentences)

    def CheckIfCorrect(self):
        if self.chosen.startswith(self.ids.input.text) == True:
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("worng")


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(TitleScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='settings'))


class TyperApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TyperApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<TitleScreen>:
    on_touch_up: root.SwitchMain()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Welcome to Typer!"
            font_size: 40
            size_hint_y:2
        Label:
            text: "Click anything to begin..."
            size_hint_y:1
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:layout
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: root.chosen
            font_size: 25
            padding: 10, 0
            text_size: root.width, None
            size: self.texture_size
            size_hint_y:3
        TextInput:
            id: input
            size_hint_y:2
            multiline: False
            #keyboard_on_key_down/up: root.CheckIfCorrect() This didn't work!
```

I expected it to print Correct in console whenever I typed correct, and Wrong when I typed incorrect. I will add more things that stop the person from typing if he typed wrong later.

Comment: In your `TextInput` rule, use `on_text: root.CheckIfCorrect()`.

Comment: You have made my day! Thanks so much!